# FlipClock - Use servertime instead of clienttime

Tags: javascript, php, flipclock

I'm trying to get a eventmonitor on 7 different Raspberry Pis.
They're all getting the same webpage with a FlipClock loaded.

My problem is: the time on the RasPis differs. (They can't get the actual ptb-time, because they are not allowed to connect to the internet)

This is how I called the Flipclock:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
  clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock',
  showSeconds: false
});
```

I thought I could solve the problem, if I get the actual date via PHP and set it while loading the FlipClock like this:

```
clock.setTime($servertime);
```

But I can't get this to work..

I'm quite new to this, so yeah, if anyone knows, how to solve it, please help me :(

EDIT:
This is how my new call looks like:

```
     <div class="clock"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var serverTime = <?= time() ?>;
   var timeDifference = new Date - serverTime;
   var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(timeDifference,{
      clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock',
      showSeconds: false
    });
  </script>
```

But this keeps my clock going strange, every refresh it takes a different hour and minute.

Comment: What's the value of `$servertime`? Should be something like `1453726200` => [epoch timestamp](http://www.epochconverter.com/)

Comment: @TimVermaelen If I echo $servertime I get `1453726371`

Comment: so when you view source, what does `var serverTime = <?= time() ?>;` look like? Also do you realize your server and the user's time will be in different timezones so your countdown will most likely be wrong?

Comment: In my source it's like this   `var serverTime = 1453726647;`

Its not a countdown, it's just a normal clock. The devices are all in the same timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread helped me... But I finally  managed to do it another way, which I think is simplier:

```
var serverTime = '<?php echo Date('H:i:s'); ?>';
var clock = $('#clock').FlipClock(serverTime,{
  clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock',
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! :)

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is ment to be executed on the Client (Browser) only, so it can **not** get the server time.
So, you have to call the Server to get the Date.
One way is using Ajax and calling a simple script that sends only the servertime back.

Another way is implementing the Servertime directly inside the Script.
If you use PHP, you can send the Time-Difference with something like that to the Script:

```
<script>
   var serverTime = <?= time() ?>
   var timeDifference = new Date - serverTime;
</script>
```

An different way is setting up a NTP Server on one of the Raspberrys, so all others can get the time from him at boot time.
Here is your solution: 
http://raspberrypi.tomasgreno.cz/ntp-client-and-server.html

Have fun!

Comment: Your time would be newDate() + timeDifference, i guess